# PySpark and Jupyter Notebook Interaction Issue in Docker Environment: Stuck Execution or Continuous Running

Tags: python, docker, apache-spark, pyspark, docker-compose

I have `docker-compose.yaml`

```yaml
version: '3'
services:
  spark-master:
    build:
      context: ./spark-master
    ports:
      - "7077:7077"
      - "8080:8080"
    command: /bin/bash ./spark-master-entrypoint.sh

  spark-worker:
    build:
      context: ./spark-worker
    command: /bin/bash ./spark-worker-entrypoint.sh
    ports:
        - "8081:8081"
        - "7078:7078"
    environment:
      - SPARK_MASTER=spark-master:7077
      - SPARK_WORKER_PORT=7078

  notebook:
    image: jupyter/all-spark-notebook
    depends_on:
      - spark-master
    environment:
      - SPARK_MASTER=spark-master
    volumes:
      - ./jupyter-notebook/notebooks:/home/jovyan
      - ./jupyter-notebook/spark/conf:/opt/spark/conf/
    ports:
        - "8888:8888"
    command: start-notebook.sh --NotebookApp.token='' --NotebookApp.password=''
```

It have 3 docker

1. spark-master
2. spark-worker
3. notebook

I want to use notebook (jupyter notebook) interact something with spark.

my notebook

```py
import os
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext

spark_master = "spark://spark-master:7077"
conf = SparkConf().setAppName("from notebook").setMaster(spark_master)
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf).getOrCreate()

rdd = sc.parallelize([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
transformed_rdd = rdd.map(lambda x: 3 * x)
result = transformed_rdd.values().collect()

print("Result from Spark:", result)
sc.stop()
```

but the notebook run and stuck at

```py
result = transformed_rdd.values().collect()
```

[image]

or
[image]
it still stuck

[image]

[image]

FYI

```
MacBook Pro (15-inch, 2017)
Processor 3.1 GHz Quad-Core Intel Core i7
Memory 16 GB 2133 MHz LPDDR3
```

Docker version

```
❯ docker compose version
Docker Compose version v2.20.2-desktop.1

❯ docker version
Client:
 Cloud integration: v1.0.35-desktop+001
 Version:           24.0.5
 API version:       1.43
 Go version:        go1.20.6
 Git commit:        ced0996
 Built:             Fri Jul 21 20:32:30 2023
 OS/Arch:           darwin/amd64
 Context:           desktop-linux

Server: Docker Desktop 4.22.1 (118664)
 Engine:
  Version:          24.0.5
  API version:      1.43 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.20.6
  Git commit:       a61e2b4
  Built:            Fri Jul 21 20:35:45 2023
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
 containerd:
  Version:          1.6.21
  GitCommit:        3dce8eb055cbb6872793272b4f20ed16117344f8
 runc:
  Version:          1.1.7
  GitCommit:        v1.1.7-0-g860f061
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.19.0
  GitCommit:        de40ad0
```

```py
for key, value in sc.getConf().getAll():
    print(f'{key}: {value}')
```

```
spark.app.id: app-20230922092957-0002
spark.app.startTime: 1695374996363
spark.driver.host: 70f40e7eb82e
spark.executor.id: driver
spark.driver.port: 42001
spark.driver.extraJavaOptions: -Djava.net.preferIPv6Addresses=false -XX:+IgnoreUnrecognizedVMOptions --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.lang.invoke=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.lang.reflect=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.net=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.nio=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.util.concurrent=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.util.concurrent.atomic=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/sun.nio.ch=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/sun.nio.cs=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/sun.security.action=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/sun.util.calendar=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.security.jgss/sun.security.krb5=ALL-UNNAMED -Djdk.reflect.useDirectMethodHandle=false
spark.app.name: from notebook
spark.rdd.compress: True
spark.master: spark://spark-master:7077
spark.serializer.objectStreamReset: 100
spark.submit.pyFiles: 
spark.submit.deployMode: client
spark.app.submitTime: 1695374996162
spark.ui.showConsoleProgress: true
spark.executor.extraJavaOptions: -Djava.net.preferIPv6Addresses=false -XX:+IgnoreUnrecognizedVMOptions --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.lang.invoke=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.lang.reflect=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.net=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.nio=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.util.concurrent=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.util.concurrent.atomic=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/sun.nio.ch=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/sun.nio.cs=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/sun.security.action=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/sun.util.calendar=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.security.jgss/sun.security.krb5=ALL-UNNAMED -Djdk.reflect.useDirectMethodHandle=false
```

What did you try?

1. define the port for worker

```
SPARK_WORKER_PORT=7078
```

from `random`

2. change service name
3. Export worker port
4. limit `SPARK_WORKER_MEMORY`
5. limit `SPARK_WORKER_CORES`

what were you expecting?

I want my pyspark and jupyter notebook run normally.

### Answer

thank Bernhard Stadler

When I change to a 32 GB machine

run not stuck

I got the error python version is not equivalent

I add

```
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y software-properties-common && \
    add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa && \
    apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y python3.11

RUN mkdir -p /opt/conda/bin
RUN ln -s /usr/bin/python3.11 /opt/conda/bin/python
```

to my `DockerFile`

and add

```
os.environ['PYSPARK_PYTHON'] = sys.executable
os.environ['PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON'] = sys.executable
```

to my notebook file

now I got the result I want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The screenshot looks like your notebook is being executed, but you have a problem in your code snippet:

```
result = transformed_rdd.values().collect()
```

As `transformed_rdd` doesn't contain tuples, you can't call `values()`. Just remove the `values()` call:

```
result = transformed_rdd.collect()
```

Comment: Thanks for the Answer but it still stuck. The next day I will try on a higher performance PC.

Comment: In that case, please add a screenshot of the page that shows when you click the application ID under "Running Applications" in the Web UI (I assume that you cancelled the old execution before trying to start the corrected version)

Comment: BTW, you should be fine with that hardware. 16GB is not huge but should be more than enough for this toy example. Or is a `-Xms` JVM parameter with a huge value used when starting the Spark Master or Workers?

Comment: I will check your answer and I add more detail In the last section of my question (for someone with the same problem). Now it's Work thank